# Parallax wordpress theme. How can i get dynamically the page ID's to display their own sub-menus?

Tags: wordpress, html, dynamic, parent-child, parallax

I'm creating a wordpress theme with parallax features and html5, the home has all the main pages and two different kind of navigations.

Main one, is the navigation for parent pages. So I have About, Projects and Contact.

But each one of this pages has child pages. About page has one child that is below it, but as i cannot access from the main menu, each page that has childs or subpages has the second type of menu.

Also projects, has different pages: "Projects" (main), "Design" (child), Consulting (child), etc.

The second menu that is placed on the right of the page as rounded buttons lists the parent "about" and the child "about 2".

I already figured it out a way to list those and to make the links behave with scroll to (parallax behavior)

But, the way that i have hardcodes the parent page. What i would like to do is to find a way to get dinamically the page ID so it won't be hardcoded, but as the theme works as a only one page site, it's making me get troubles.

Here is the code that i have, could anyone help me to find a way so the code is going to identify the ID of each current page to list the main and the children pages ?

As you see `$parent = 13;` is hardcoded, and also it includes `$pages = get_pages('hierarchical=0&include=13') ;` with the id hardcoded too. So all the pages are showing the same. I know i can create a conditional with is_page for each hardcoding it, but the idea is to make it dynamic.

Any help will be great!

THanks,

```
<?php 

$parent = 13;
$args= array(
    'parent' => $parent,
    'hierarchical' => 0
);

            $pages = get_pages('hierarchical=0&include=13') ;

            foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                $new_title = str_replace( " ", "", strtolower( $page->post_name ) );    
                echo '<li><a href="#' . $new_title . '" title="' . $page->post_title . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';
            }

    $child_page_pages = get_pages($args);
    foreach ( $child_page_pages as $page ) {

                $new_title = str_replace( " ", "", strtolower( $page->post_name ) );    
                echo '<li><a href="#' . $new_title . '" title="' . $page->post_title . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a></li>';
            }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get post parent page ID's you can use `get_post_ancestors( $post )` it should return the parent ID.

```
$ReturnParents = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
```

Another method you can try is the global `$post`.

```
global $post;
global $wp_query; 

    $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID; 
    $myParent = $post->post_parent; 

    echo "I am post ". $thePostID . " and my parent is " . $myParent;
```

Comment: With global $post every page returns the same: "I am post 1 and my parent is 0" so I'm having each page on the parallax theme saying that is the post number 1. And none of the pages ID is #1. What I'm doing wrong?